# Accessing the properties of a user control via XAML

Tags: wpf, user-controls

I've created a user control that is a `Button` with a `TextBlock` and an `Image` assigned to it:

```
<UserControl x:Class="App_Designer.Resources.ucDropDownButton" ... />
<StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10">
<Button x:Name="ButtonDropDown">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Name="imgButton" Margin="0,0,5,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"             x:FieldModifier="public"></Image>
        <TextBlock Name="txtButtonContent" x:FieldModifier="public"></TextBlock>
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

If I reference it on my page:

`<local:ucDropDownButton x:Name="btnAddImportTemplate" />`

How do I set the contents of the txtButtonContent `TextBlock` in the XAML? I assumed I'd be able to write :

`<local:ucDropDownButton x:Name="btnAddImportTemplate" txtButtonContent.Text="whatever" />`

I know I can do it in code with `btnAddImportTemplate.txtButtonContent.Text = "whatever";`
but I'd like to be able to set it in the XAML itself. I added the x:FieldModifier after researching the issue but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add a public property onto the User Control class

```
public partial class ucDropDownButton
{
   public string MyText
   {
       get { return txtButtonContent.Text }
      set { txtButtonContent.Text = value }
   }

 // Rest of the class

}
```

MyText will now be possible to set from XAML

Comment: Thanks for that! It seems so obvious now you've mentioned it, I've still not fully got into the way of WPF thinking.